# Wizard before showing the shell wpf

Tags: wpf, prism, mef

I have a wpf application, which has file menu and can open and save projects. I am using Prism and MEF.

Now I need to have a wizard showing the user:

1. To continue as usual
2. MRU history so that he can load the project to the work area by double clicking.

MRU service is also in a module(dll), which we add to the catalog in mefbootstrapper.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Essentially, you are navigating from one page (the wizard) to another (the shell's view). Another way to see this is as two different views (Wizard and Shell) over the same ViewModel. In either case you need to create the wizard view and navigate to the shell view

Comment: Yes, I will create the wizardview but it uses one of the modules(MRU) to show the recentlist, to use [Import] in the wizardview it needs to be registered in the catalog and the container should have to deliver it on demand. I am confused how to achieve this.

Comment: Why would you exactly need to load and show the wizard before loading the Shell View? Using OnDemand modules as you mentioned you could create an initial generic View, perform the Bootstrapper tasks and then show the Wizard which would decide the flow of the app according to the user choice. As the Modules would be loading OnDemand, you would not be initializing unnecessary Modules or objects. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, there would be no need to show the **Wizard** before loading the `Shell`:

Using ***OnDemand*** modules as you mentioned, you could create an initial generic `ShellView`, perform the **Bootstrapper** tasks and finally show the **Wizard** with the `Shell` and **Bootstrapper** already initialized, and the **Wizard** would then decide the flow of the app according to the user choice.

As the **Modules** would be loading ***OnDemand***, you would not be initializing unnecessary **Modules** or objects.

Regards.